# How to find out available fonts from within Mathematica?

Tags: front-end, fonts, rendering

How to find out available fonts on the system from within Mathematica?  When I do

```
Style["foobar", FontFamily -> "Foobar"]
```

how do I know which font the displayed output is using/falling back to use?

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859424

Comment: If you want to know what font the output is, you can highlight the text and open the text window (Ctrl + T or Cmd + T). For my system, your command leads to text in 'Lucida Grand'.

Comment: I think kguler's answer in vitaliy's link is exactly what you're looking for... He's active on this site, so he'll be around soon to answer it himself

Comment: yep ``FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListFonts"]][[All, 2]]``

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The relevant line from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859424/how-to-programmatically-obtain-information-about-font-selection-in-mathematica):

```
fontlist = FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListFonts"]];
```

**Update:** The content of the `"MenuListFonts"` list is system-dependent. In Windows Vista, I get a list that contains only `FontFamily`:

```
 Panel@Row[fontlist[[;; 60]] /.
 Rule[x_, y_] :> Style[ToString@x, 14, FontFamily -> y],  " \[FilledSquare] "]
```

[image]

On a Mac system, it appears that the list contains tuples of `FontFamily, FontWeight` and `FontSlant`. That is,

```
fontlist /. Rule[x_, y_] :> Style[x, 20, FontFamily -> y]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: FWIW even though i did not accept your answer at the time back when I asked the question linked by Vitaly (I chose a different one) your answer is actually the one I am regularly now using.

Comment: Thank you @Mike. The problem in your question still waits for a more direct solution -- everytime I come accross a new `CurrentValue` argument I wonder if it can be used for that problem.