# What is the full list of all font families?

Tags: front-end, fonts

I'm having trouble finding a complete list of the `FontFamily` strings that *Mathematica* supports.

Comment: does this [How to find out available fonts from within Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10044/125) answer your question?

Comment: @kguler. The answer you link to reports all the fonts available to _Mathematica_ on a particular system. That is has many more entries than the list of font families. A font family can contain many fonts.

Comment: @m_goldberg, the image in that answer definitely supports your observation. That image is posted by Szabolcs, and, most likely, it is what you get on a Mac system.) On Windows (Vista) I get a list that has only the font family (not family/slant/weight tuples).

Comment: FontFamily help: "Mathematica will combine settings for FontFamily, FontWeight, FontSlant, FontTracking, and sometimes FontSize to construct a complete name for the font you want. It will then use this name, together with any settings you have specified for FontPostScriptName and FontNativeName to try to locate an appropriate font on your particular computer system." And then there's FontSubstitutions...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a Windows system, the solution suggested in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10044/125)

```
fontlist = FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListFonts"]]
```

gives the `FontFamily`s in the form of rules:

```
fontlist[[;; 5]]
```

> {"Agency FB" -> "Agency FB", "Aharoni" -> "Aharoni", 
>         "Algerian" -> "Algerian", "Amienne" -> "Amienne", "Andalus" -> "Andalus"}

and the list of font families can be obtained by taking the first `Part`s of the elements in `fontlist`:

```
fontlist[[;; 5]][[All,1]]
```

> {"Agency FB", "Aharoni", "Algerian", "Amienne", "Andalus"}

As noted by @m_goldberg in the comments above, one gets tuples of `FontFamily`, `FontWeight` and `FontSlant` on a Mac system. The output is *similar* to what one gets on a Windows system from the following code:

```
fontlistMac = Thread[# -> #] &[Join @@ ({#, StringJoin[{#, " ", "Bold"}],
    StringJoin[{#, " ", "Italic"}],
    StringJoin[{#, " ", "Bold", " ", "Italic"}]} & /@ 
fontlist[[;; 5]][[All, 1]])];
Panel[%]
```

[image]

So, to get the list of `FontFamily`s without duplication, one needs to filter the result using something like

```
DeleteDuplicates[StringTrim@StringReplace[#, "Bold" | "Italic" :> ""] & /@ 
  macFntLst[[All, 1]]]
```

> {"Agency FB", "Aharoni", "Algerian", "Amienne", "Andalus"}

Comment: Interesting, but aren't there lots of duplicates in there?

Comment: @cormullion, thank you.. updated with corrections.

Comment: It's a good first pass for Mac users, so +1, but it would need many more tweaks and additions to do the job 100% accurately. I can see things like Light, Oblique, Black, Heavy, ExtraBlack, Semibold, Condensed, Regular, Demi, Narrow, Ultra - plus abbreviations of these... A mess... :)

Answer (score 8):

As of version 10.1 you can use [`$FontFamilies`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$FontFamilies.html).

From the documentation:

> `$FontFamilies` gives the list of the font families available to the
>   Wolfram System.

For me `$FontFamilies` yields an accurate representations on the fonts I have installed on my system (v10.3.1 on Win10).

Comment: Only if there is a Front-End available, `$FontFamilies` returns and empty list on *Wolfram Engine*.