# How to get a list of available appearance/styles/Methods?

Tags: documentation, undocumented, gui-construction

This is a basic question but I haven't found any answer yet :/

Available appearances for `Button[]` are mentioned in `Help`, those are `"Palette"`, `"FramedPalette"`, `"DialogBox"` and so on. But is this all? How could I get to know?
For example there is also used in Help `"NoOp"` option in `MouseAppearance[]`.

Are there any others in addition to those mentioned in `Help`.

Is there somewhere more info about styles but for different functions too?

Comment: Dear reader, you may find the answer at the bottom interesting :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This answer in not the answer you want.

There are almost certainly more options for a button's appearance than are documented in the Help Center. As far a I know there is no way to discover what  appearance options apply to buttons. This seems to be a deliberate policy on the part of WRI.

I recently had a exchange of email with WRI tech suppor on a related matter, `SetterBar`. This was their position on that subject:

> Many functions like SetterBar have optional arguments
>   available which are not documented. Typically this is because the options
>   are not ready to be exposed because we haven't been able to fully test them
>   or because their behavior isn't fully ready yet. We don't provide any
>   documentation on them because their behavior is not guaranteed and they may
>   not be present in a future version of Mathematica. We do not actively
>   prevent people from using these hidden options however if they find them
>   useful.

Comment: Information that there is no answer is also important :) It will save my time. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I decided to create a repository of usually undocumented lists (*or just a links to similar topics*) of available options:

- [**AppearanceElements for Manipulate** and friends](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46792/5478)
- [**MouseAppearance** styles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19290/5478)
- [All **Font families**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18906/5478)
- [All the Properties that **ColorData** supports?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76612/5478)

---

- [`Events` for `EventHandler`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6207/5478). AFAICT additional two that work: `"MouseExited"/"MouseEntered"`
- `EventHandler` and `MenuItem`: [`"Save"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27459/5478), [`"HandleShiftReturn"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6459/5478)

---

- [Items known by `CurrentValue`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1379/5478)
- [Valid `FrontEndTokens`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2572/5478)
- [Valid `FrontEnd` `Packet` types](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13451/5478) ***(New)***

---

- [`Solve Method`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47753/5478)

---

#### Basic references:

- [Inline documentation of “Properties”](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77056/5478) ***(New)***
- [How to find undocumented options...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/5478)
- [What are some useful, undocumented Mathematica functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805/5478)

#### Feel free to add a link if you know any other.