# How to get all possible Rules and Elements of Functions like ExportString

Tags: export, options

Here are some `$ExportFormats`.

I'd like to know which one has some options or elements of Import and Export.

```
 $ExportFormats

 (* {3DS,ACO,AIFF,AU,AVI,Base64,Binary,Bit,BMP,Byte,BYU,BZIP2,C,CDF,Character16,
     Character8,Complex128,Complex256,Complex64,CSV,CUR,DICOM,DIF,DIMACS,DOT,DXF,
     EMF,EPS,ExpressionML,FASTA,FASTQ,FCS,FITS,FLAC,FLV,GIF,Graph6,Graphlet,GraphML,
     GXL,GZIP,HarwellBoeing,HDF,HDF5,HTML,ICNS,ICO,Integer128,Integer16,Integer24,
     Integer32,Integer64,Integer8,JPEG,JPEG2000,JSON,JVX,KML,LEDA,List,LWO,MAT,
     MathML,Maya,MGF,MIDI,MOL,MOL2,MTX,MX,NASACDF,NB,NetCDF,NEXUS,NOFF,OBJ,OFF,
     Package,Pajek,PBM,PCX,PDB,PDF,PGM,PLY,PNG,PNM,POV,PPM,PXR,QuickTime,RawBitmap,
     Real128,Real32,Real64,RIB,RTF,SCT,SDF,SND,Sparse6,STL,String,SurferGrid,SVG,SWF,
     Table,TAR,TerminatedString,TeX,Text,TGA,TGF,TIFF,TSV,UnsignedInteger128,
     UnsignedInteger16,UnsignedInteger24,UnsignedInteger32,UnsignedInteger64,
     UnsignedInteger8,UUE,VideoFrames,VRML,VTK,WAV,Wave64,WDX,WMF,X3D,XBM,XHTML,
     XHTMLMathML,XLS,XLSX,XML,XYZ,ZIP,ZPR} *)
```

```
 ExportString[expr, "format"]
```

generates a string corresponding to expr exported in the specified format.

```
 ExportString[rules, {"format", "Rules"}]
```

gives explicit rules for different elements of the data to be exported.

```
 ExportString[exprs, elems]
```

generates a string by treating exprs as elements specified by elems.

#### example

---

Tex and HTML have some rules

```
 ExportString[something, "Tex", someRules]

 ExportString[something, "HTML", "FullDocument" -> False]
```

when in the `ref/ExportString` page, we cannot find more informations about these `Rules` and `Elements`.

Though in `ref/format/TEX` we can find the options of Exporting `Tex`, as well as in `ref/format/HTML`

So how to get all these options and elements something like `Options[]` or `Names[]`
You know even for some frequently used formats I cannot memorize all things.
Sometimes searched in Help Pages just to know one OptionName for spelling purpose.

For instance: "Plaintext" or "PlainText" ? "Tex" or "TeX"? They are string, and not in command completion.

Maybe we can add them to command completion?

And further can we add some options to some build-in functions?

Comment: Since many of the formats are not related to one another at all, I'm not sure how meaningful it is to ask for all of the possible options for every one. Why not just look at the documentation for the format(s) that you're interested in?

Comment: @OleksandrR. Even for some frequently used formats like `HTML` and `Tex`, I've looked at the documentation for many times, if there is one function, I can get the information quickly that would be better.

Comment: @OleksandrR. One reason, I'd like the Command Completion for some string option name if possible. Otherwise one memo table is helpful for me to spell the string option names correctly.

Comment: I think this question is answered, in part at least, [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18918/how-to-get-a-list-of-available-appearance-styles)