# What are the Method options Solve command accepts?

Tags: equation-solving, options

What are the Method options Solve command accepts? Solve has the Method option, however documentation contains no methods that it accepts...

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/131

Comment: The documentation for `Solve` mentions that `Method -> Reduce` can be given in place of `Method -> Automatic`. It is implied, but not explicitly stated, that these are the only methods available.

Answer (score 5):

Undocumented [`Method->"Legacy"` option forces `Solve` in version 8 to use algorithm from versions <=7](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Nov/msg00787.html).

```
exprs = Together[{(b + d + f)/x - (a + b)/(1 + x) - 
     2*(c + d + e)/(1 + 2*x + y) - (f + g)/(x + y), (e + g)/
      y - (c + d + e)/(1 + 2*x + y) - (f + g)/(x + y)}];
Timing[solns1 = Solve[exprs == 0, {x, y}, Method -> "Legacy"];]
```

> {39.515, Null}

`Solve[exprs == 0, {x, y}]` never returns in version 8. Additional examples see [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/17961).

Some information on the change in the algorithm between versions 7 and 8 is [published](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/158746) by Bruce Miller (Wolfram Technical Support Group):

> Boilerplate I had:
>
> The difference between 7.0 and 8.0 output is that 7.0 Solve was
>   treating equations that involved only variables as assumptions. This
>   functionality was not precisely defined or consistently implemented
>   and has been removed in 8.0.  Instead there is a new option
>   MaxExtraConditions which provides a well-defined and extended version
>   of the functionality.

Answer (score 4):

With `Method -> Reduce`, `Solve` uses only equivalent transformations and finds all solutions.

```
Solve[x E^x == 1/2, x, Method -> Reduce]
```

> ```
> {{x -> ConditionalExpression[ProductLog[C[1], 1/2], C[1] ∈ Integers]}}
> ```

Comment: @Öskå. From my reading of the documentation, I conclude `Reduce` and `Automatic` are the only method choices available. So I think this a valid answer.

Comment: @m_goldberg Although it would be "great" to have a function giving the available method for `Solve` or `NDSolve` or any function taking `Method` as `Options`. But you are right, in the case of `Solve` it might be the only ones.