# Solve slower in versions 9 and 10

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, backslide

With some systems of equations, `Solve` is much slower in versions 9 and 10 than in earlier versions, apparently because it is doing more simplification of the results.

With the following example linear system:

```
eqs = {0 == g1 - 2 g1 r[1, 1] - I oa r[1, 3] + I oa r[3, 1] + g2 r[3, 3],
   0 == -I da r[1, 2] + I db r[1, 2] - 2 g1 r[1, 2] - I ob r[1, 3] + I oa r[3, 2],
   0 == -I oa r[1, 1] - I ob r[1, 2] - I da r[1, 3] - 2 g1 r[1, 3] - g2 r[1, 3] + I oa r[3, 3],
   0 == I da r[2, 1] - I db r[2, 1] - 2 g1 r[2, 1] - I oa r[2, 3] + I ob r[3, 1],
   0 == g1 - 2 g1 r[2, 2] - I ob r[2, 3] + I ob r[3, 2] + g2 r[3, 3],
   0 == -I oa r[2, 1] - I ob r[2, 2] - I db r[2, 3] - 2 g1 r[2, 3] - g2 r[2, 3] + I ob r[3, 3],
   0 == I oa r[1, 1] + I ob r[2, 1] + I da r[3, 1] - 2 g1 r[3, 1] - g2 r[3, 1] - I oa r[3, 3],
   0 == I oa r[1, 2] + I ob r[2, 2] + I db r[3, 2] - 2 g1 r[3, 2] - g2 r[3, 2] - I ob r[3, 3],
   0 == I oa r[1, 3] + I ob r[2, 3] - I oa r[3, 1] - I ob r[3, 2] - 2 g1 r[3, 3] - 2 g2 r[3, 3]
   };
vars = {r[1, 1], r[1, 2], r[1, 3], r[2, 1], r[2, 2], r[2, 3], r[3, 1], r[3, 2], r[3, 3]};

{$VersionNumber, Round[First@Timing[sol = Solve[eqs, vars];], .01], LeafCount@sol}
```

I get the results:

\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{Version} & \text{Timing} & \text{LeafCount} \\
 6. & 0.19 & 219384 \\
 7. & 0.08 & 227942 \\
 8. & 1.82 & 86317 \\
 9. & 63.32 & 29452 \\
 10.2 & 30.84 & 82043 \\
\end{array}

Version 10 was run on a 2.3GHz MacBook Pro, earlier versions were run on an older 2.4GHz PC. (Note that if the `Solve` command is executed twice, the second time is faster, presumably due to some caching of results. The timings are all for the first evaluation.)

So there is an inverse correlation between `Timing` and `LeafCount`, which makes sense if extra time is being taken for some sort of simplification. But for my purposes the ~3x reduction in `LeafCount` between versions 7 and 10 is not worth the ~400x slowdown.

Does anyone happen to know if there's an undocumented `Method` setting to get `Solve` to use a method from an earlier version? Or maybe some other workaround?

#### Update 1:

`Solve` with `Method -> "Legacy"` (suggested by [Alexey Popkov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280/alexey-popkov)) and `` System`Private`OldSolve `` (suggested by [Guess who](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/guess-who-it-is)) both give me a timing of 18.7 s and a `LeafCount` of 44087 on 10.2. So it seems that they are both doing the same thing. It's supposed to [cause `Solve` to use the version 7 algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47756/8253), but it's clearly not using the exact algorithm from version 7. Using `Method -> "Legacy"` in different versions I get

\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{Version} & \text{Timing} & \text{LeafCount} \\
 8. & 1.78 & 48622 \\
 9. & 21.92 & 27358 \\
 10.2 & 18.77 & 44087 \\
\end{array}

So for this system of equations it's an improvement in both timing and leaf count in all versions, but still nowhere close to version 7's speed.

#### Update 2:

As pointed out in [Michael E2's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89658/8253), we can do much better with `LinearSolve`, and we can transfer this benefit to `Solve` by setting the options for `RowReduce`, as suggested by [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau).

After setting

```
SetOptions[RowReduce, Method -> "CofactorExpansion"]
```

`Solve` gives the results

\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{Version} & \text{Timing} & \text{LeafCount} \\
 6. & 0.42 & 64004 \\
 7. & 0.42 & 64004 \\
 8. & 0.5 & 67879 \\
 9. & 0.5 & 67879 \\
 10.2 & 0.27 & 67879 \\
\end{array}

Now it's reasonably fast, and stable across versions. It doesn't beat the default `Solve` in version 7 for speed, or version 9 for leaf count, but it seems like a good overall compromise.

Comment: A good question! And very nice previous research. +10 if I could.

Comment: Very interesting! Just to add one more data point at least for `LeafCount`, this is the result on MMA 10.2 on Win7-64: {10.2, 24.4, 82043}.

Comment: @belisarius Thanks. I did the research almost by accident -- it's an example from the documentation of a package I'm developing for versions 6 and later. So I was testing the docs in different versions...

Comment: Funny thing is it is about 25% slower on my machine when I use NSolve instead of Solve.

Comment: With [`Method -> "Legacy"`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47756/280) added to `Solve` I get with MMa 10.2 on Win7 x64: `{10.2, 20.16, 45770}`. Without this option I get `{10.2, 25.19, 82043}`.

Comment: Changing from version 7 to version 10 I knew some things became slower, but nothing to this degree!  I know that performance is a balancing act but this seems to really need some attention.  The system could at least provide the old method as an option, and even attempt to evaluate it in parallel to see if it works better.

Comment: I don't have the new version, but just in case: I believe *Mathematica* might still have something called `OldSolve[]` lying around, but I'm not sure which context it's in. You could try that...

Comment: On my machine: Windows 10, i5-4200U 1.6GHz, 
without any tuning {10.3, 25.16, 71790}; 
with Method -> "Legacy", {10.3, 19.22, 41925}; 
with RowReduce, {10.3, 0.34, 67879}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is best I can do so far.  The system is linear so [`LinearSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve.html) is a natural thing to try.

```
arrays = CoefficientArrays[eqs, vars]
(*  {SparseArray[< 2 >, {9}], SparseArray[< 35 >, {9, 9}]}  *)

solv1 = Thread[
    vars -> LinearSolve[arrays[[2]], -arrays[[1]], 
      Method -> "CofactorExpansion"]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.28347, Null}  *)
```

I cannot figure out how to get `Solve` to make this call or its equivalent.

---

With Daniel and Simon's help, here is how to do it with `Solve`:

```
With[{opts = Options[RowReduce]},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetOptions[RowReduce, Method -> "CofactorExpansion"],
  Solve[eqs, vars]; // AbsoluteTiming,
  SetOptions[RowReduce, opts]
  ]]
(*  {0.282098, Null}  *)
```

Comment: `SetOptions[RowReduce, Method -> "OneStepRowReduction"]` will do what you have in mind; `Solve` goes through `RowReduce` at least for nonsparse linear systems.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks. However `Solve` took 7.4 sec, considerably longer than `LinearSolve`, with the `RowReduce` option set.  I thought perhaps `Solve` is not selecting to solve as a linear system because of the symbolic parameters or because the variables have the form `{r[1, 1], r[1, 2],...}` -- shots in the dark, admittedly.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on. For me it was quite fast. I may recheck if I get some time free later.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I'm using V10.2 on a Mac, if that's any help.

Comment: I think maybe @DanielLichtblau meant to set `SetOptions[RowReduce, Method -> "CofactorExpansion"]` -- that gives comparable results to your `LinearSolve` method on my computer.

Comment: Setting the options for `RowReduce` seems to work well (see the update to the question). If you add this to your answer I'll accept.

Comment: @SimonRochester Thanks for figuring that out.  I added my way of using the option to my answer.

Comment: Thank you @SimonRochester. I managed to not notice the error. Twice.