# What are all the Properties that ColorData supports?

Tags: color, undocumented, properties

The documentation for [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html) reads:

> Possible properties in ColorData["scheme","property"] include:
>
> ```
> "ColorFunction"
> "ColorList"
> "ColorRules"
> "Image"
> "Name"
> "Panel"
> "ParameterCount"
> "Range"
> {"Range",i}
> ```

Are there any others?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Evaluating `ColorData["Properties"]` in 10.0.2 returns:

```
{"AlternateNames", "ColorFunction", "ColorList", "ColorRules",
 "Image", "Name", "Panel", "ParameterCount", "Range", "StandardName"}
```

This however is also incomplete.  Some spelunking reveals that there are more.  Here is a complete list from the function definition itself:

```
"StandardName"
"Name"
"AlternateNames"
"PrivateStandardNames"
"ColorFunction"
"ColorList"
{"ColorList", "Sorted"}
"ColorRules"
{"ColorRules", "Sorted"}
"Range"
{"Range", _Integer?Positive}
"ParameterCount"
"Image"
"Panel"
"ColorNames"
{"ColorNames", "Sorted"}
"BlendArgument"
"PrivateNote"
```

Comment: I think it would be good to mention that a user can get most of these by evaluating `ColorData["Properties"]`, which produces `{"AlternateNames", "ColorFunction", "ColorList", "ColorRules", "Image", "Name", "Panel", "ParameterCount", "Range", "StandardName"}`. In general, evaluating `someData["Properties"] usually produces useful info about `someData`.

Comment: @m_goldberg That's a good point, but as that data is now known to be incomplete I was uncertain of the value of mentioning it.

Comment: Nice. `{ColorData[#, "AlternateNames"] // First, ColorData[#, "Panel"]} & /@  ColorData["Indexed"] // Grid`