# Specify range and reverse for colordata in contourplot

Tags: plotting, color

The following two examples work

```
ContourPlot[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 1}}]]
ContourPlot[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", "Reverse"}]]
```

I want to combine those two options, but the following does not work

```
ContourPlot[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", "Reverse", {1, 0}}]]
```

The last plot is just black and I get the message

```
ColorData::notent: {TemperatureMap, Reverse, {1, 0}} is not a known entity,
class, or tag for ColorData. Use ColorData[] for a list of entities."
```

The above is just some minimum working example, and if you wonder why I want to do this, read the following: I am making several contourplots that I want to have the same color representing the same values, so I need to specify the values. I also have one set of plots that go from negative to 0, and one set that goes from 0 to some positive value. In the negative case the most negative value represents the largest effect, while in the positive case the most positive value represents the largest effect. I want largest effect in both cases to have the deepest color, so I need to invert one of the colorgradients.

Help is much appreciated.

[image]

**Edit**

I was a bit unclear earlier, but I'll try to calrify now. I have made some more plots to illustrate what I mean. Sorry for the lengthy code.

```
myColRange[range_] := ColorData[{"StarryNightColors", range}];
cont = 15;

GraphicsGrid[{{

   ContourPlot[
    -Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
     ColorFunction -> myColRange[{-3, 0}],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    Contours -> cont,
    PlotLabel -> 
   "-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(\(-\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \
   \(2\)]\) - \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)]\)]\)"],

   Plot3D[
    -Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
    ColorFunction -> myColRange[{-3, 0}],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-3, 0}},
    PlotLabel -> 
     "-\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(\(-\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \
     \(2\)]\) - \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)]\)]\)"],

   ContourPlot[
    -3 Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
    ColorFunction -> myColRange[{-3, 0}],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    Contours -> cont,
    PlotLabel -> 
      "-3\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(\(-\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \
      \(2\)]\) - \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)]\)]\)"],

   Plot3D[
    -3 Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
    ColorFunction -> myColRange[{-3, 0}],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-3, 0}},
    PlotLabel -> 
      "-3\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(\(-\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \
      \(2\)]\) - \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)]\)]\)"]},

  {ContourPlot[
    Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
    ColorFunction -> myColRange[{0, 3}],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Contours -> cont,
    PlotLabel -> 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(\(-\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\
     \) - \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)]\)]\)"],

   Plot3D[
    Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
    ColorFunction -> myColRange[{0, 3}],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 3}},
    PlotLabel -> 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(\(-\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\
      \) - \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)]\)]\)"],

   ContourPlot[
    3 Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
    ColorFunction -> myColRange[{0, 3}],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Contours -> cont,
    PlotLabel -> 
     "3\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(\(-\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \
       \(2\)]\) - \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)]\)]\)"],

   Plot3D[
    3 Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
    ColorFunction -> myColRange[{0, 3}],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 3}},
    PlotLabel -> 
     "3\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(\(-\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \
      \(2\)]\) - \*SuperscriptBox[\(y\), \(2\)]\)]\)"]}},

 ImageSize -> Large]
```

The code generates these plots

[image]

I am interested in the contourplots, but included the 3D plots to better illustrate what I want.

If you look at one row, the plots have the same range. In the first row the colors changes from -3 to 0, and in the second from 0 to 3. I want to keep it like that: plots in a row have the same scale on the colordata. The scale does not need to be the same for the two different rows, they just happen to be 0 and |3| here because I copy pasted.

What I want now is to reverse the colors of the positive plots in row 2, but I would like to keep the shape of the plot. So I want the peaks to be dark, and then grow lighter closer to 0.

I tried with the pure function proposed by JasonB, but then I get this

```
 myColPure[range_] := (ColorData[{"StarryNightColors", range}][1 - #] &)
```

[image]

Comment: @JasonB Sorry, I just realized i copied the wrong code! I have edited my question now. My question was supposed to be for contourplots, and I can't get your answers to work for them. They worked perfectly for Plot3D tho :)

Comment: The difference between the color function for `Plot3D` and for `ContourPlot` is that with `ContourPlot` only one possible value is fed to the color function, the contour level.  For `Plot3D` it can be given the x, y, or z values and you need to use the 3rd slot to scale it with the z value, so just `#` for `ContourPlot` and `#3` for `Plot3D`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think everyone is overlooking the simplest way:

- If you want a range of `{0, 3}` but also reversed, just specify it as `{3, 0}`:

:-) Magic:

```
Plot3D[-3 Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"StarryNightColors", {-3, 0}}],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-3, 0}}
]

Plot3D[3 Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"StarryNightColors", {3, 0}}],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 3}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, that is a bit embarrassing to have overlooked that :-)

Comment: Wow yes this is a bit simpler :)

Comment: @EspenBrun Thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't seem as though you **can** specify more than one *property* for a `ColorData` object.  So if you want to reverse it the order of the colors, you can do that with the "Reverse" property, and you can reverse the range by applying a pure function to the inputs.

Change your color function to this:

```
myColRange[range_] := 
  Function[x, 
   ColorData[{"StarryNightColors", "Reversed"}][
    Rescale[Abs[x], range]]];
```

and also redefine your `cont` so that the lines are at the same levels for each plot (so they have a consistent meaning)

```
cont = Subdivide[-3, 3, 30];
```

and now your contour plots look like this:

[image]

Comment: This reverses the plot twice, right? Instead of having the "Reverse", I would like to give the range that the colors should be scaled to.

I would like to have several contourplots,  say

Exp[-x^2 - y^2]
 2 x Exp[-x^2 - y^2]
3 x Exp[-x^2 - y^2]

I want the colors to represent the same values inn all three plots, so that the first will be more blue etc

Comment: Yeah, I'm still confused about what you want to do.  What you wrote in your example, `ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", "Reverse", {1, 0}}]`, if that worked that is exactly what it would do - it would reverse the color function twice.

Comment: I think you just need to do what halirutan suggests, define the `myColAbs` and turn `ColorFunctionScaling` to `False`

Comment: Thanks for your comments :) I have edited my post yet again to better illustrate what I mean, since I was pretty unclear. I tried to use your pure function, but I could not get it to work.

Comment: @EspenBrun let me know if that is what you needed.

Comment: Yes! Those look excactly like what I want, and it works perfectly :D A thousand thanks to you, sir.

Comment: FYI: `"Reverse"` is not a *property*, it is a *range*.  Properties are separate, and I listed them here for reference: [(76612)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76612/121)

Answer (score 4):

You have another problem that you haven't considered: Plotting-functions like `Plot3D` will scale their values. So if you have as example, all negative values like here

```
Plot3D[-Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 1}}]]
```

[image: gr]

The plot will still be colored, although you explicitly specified the range to be {0,1}. Therefore, if you need to work with values directly from the surface, then you need to specify `ColorFunctionScaling->False`.

The rest can be done by simply making your own function from `ColorData`. Jason already showed how to do this with anonymous functions. Let me show the explicit way:

```
myColAbs[val_] := ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Abs[val]]

Plot3D[-Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> myColAbs,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False
]
```

et voila:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the insight regarding the pure function and ColorFunctionScaling -> False got me one step closer. I was a bit unclear in my post what i really wanted though, so I have edited it again.