# BarChart and ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, color, visualization, charts

There are really two questions. The first is: how does one get BarChart to generate x coordinates. That is, `ListPlot` takes a list of pairs, but `BarChart` takes a list of y-values only. Is there any way to impart x values to it?

Second question (which is related, because I am using `BarChart` so I can use `ColorFunction`) is: how do I invert `ColorFunction`. That is, "DarkRainbow" makes high values red, low values green. I want it exactly the other way around. What's the trick?

Comment: For the x-values, I'm not sure that's easily possible, since `BarChart` is not designed for that - it might be easier to use `Histogram` with `WeightedData` to achieve that effect. Maybe there is an easy solution for your particular case, but we can't say more unless you specify what kinds of x values you want. For the `ColorFunction` part, you can access the color function specified by a string using [`ColorData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html). It is then straightforward to flip the function by wrapping it in a `Function`

Comment: `ColorData[{"DarkRainbow", {1, 0}}]` will give reversed color; see [(106152)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/106152/121) for another example.

Answer (score 6):

### Reversing ColorFunction

To *reverse* `"DarkRainbow"` color scheme, you can use `ColorData[{"DarkRainbow", "Reverse"}]` (or `ColorData[{"DarkRainbow", "Reversed"}]`):

```
Row[{BarChart[{2, 1, 3, 4}, 
      ColorFunction ->"DarkRainbow", 
       PlotLabel ->Style[ "DarkRainbow",16], 
       ImageSize -> 300],
    BarChart[{2, 1, 3, 4}, 
       ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"DarkRainbow", "Reverse"}],
       PlotLabel ->Style[HoldForm @ ColorData[{"DarkRainbow", "Reverse"}], 16], 
       ImageSize -> 300]} , 
    Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

### Adding horizontal coordinates

#### BarChart + custom ChartElementFunction

To add x-coordinates you can attach the desired coordinates to input data as metadata and use a custom `ChartElementFunction` to translate the bars according to the metadata associated with each bar:

```
data = {2, 1, 3, 4};
SeedRandom[7]
xcoords = Sort @ RandomSample[Range[20], 4]
```

> {5, 11, 14, 18}

```
cEF = ChartElementData["Rectangle"][{#3[[1]] + 
  {-(#[[1, 2]] - #[[1, 1]])/2, (#[[1, 2]] - #[[1, 1]])/ 2}, #[[2]]}, ##2] &;

Show[BarChart[Thread[data -> xcoords], 
    ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
    ChartElementFunction -> cEF], 
    Axes -> False,
    Frame -> True]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

#### BarChart + post-processing

An alternative way is to post-process the `BarChart` output to horizontally translate the rectangles by amounts given by `xcoords`:

```
bc = BarChart[data, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", BarSpacing -> 0, Axes -> False];

Show[Module[{k = 1}, bc /. r : Rectangle[{a_, _}, {b_, _}, ___] :> 
    Translate[r, {xcoords[[k++]] - (a + b)/2, 0}]], 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

#### BarChart + pre-processing

We can also pre-process input data to inject non-numeric values between specified x coordinates:

```
heights = Normal @ SparseArray[Thread[xcoords -> data], 19, Null] ;

BarChart[heights,
  ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", ChartLabels -> Range[20], Frame->True]
```

[image]

#### Histogram + custom height function

```
heightf = Normal @ SparseArray[Thread[xcoords -> data], 19] ;

Histogram[{1}, {.5, 20, 1}, heightf&, 
  ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", Frame -> True]
```

[image]

#### Histogram + WeightedData

Using `Histogram` as suggested by Lukas in comments is much easier:

```
Histogram[WeightedData[xcoords, data], {-.5, 20, 1},
  ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", Frame -> True]
```

[image]