# How to get properties of ColorDataFunction objects programmatically?

Tags: graphics, programming, color

The display forms of `ColorDataFunction` objects (especially after one clicks on the white `+` sign on them) indicate that these objects have properties like `Name`, `Class`, etc.  For example:

```
ColorData["StarryNightColors"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ColorData[60]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

---

I'd like to write a function that takes a `ColorDataFunction` object as an argument.  How can this function access the properties of a `ColorDataFunction` object?

---

FWIW, expressions like the ones below won't work:

```
ColorData[60, "ColorFunction", "Properties"]

ColorData[60, "ColorFunction"]["Properties"]
```

Comment: you can get somewhere inspecting `FullForm` and then addressing parts, eg `ColorData[60, "ColorFunction"][[2]]->"Indexed"`.  Not very satisfactory though.

Comment: Related: [(76612)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76612/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ColorDataFunction` is not atomic,

```
cdf = ColorData["StarryNightColors"];

AtomQ@cdf
(* False *)
```

so you have direct access to the arguments.  Just replace the head with `List` and you have the four items listed in the box

```
List @@ cdf
(* {"StarryNightColors", "Gradients", {0, 1}, Blend["StarryNightColors", #1] &} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, I am only talking about the most important property of ColorDataFunction, because you can use FullForm to get the other properties.

There is some additional information.
ColorData[scheme] returns a ColorDataFunction. You can use the returned ColorDataFunction directly.

If you check the definition of ColorDataFunction, you will see only Function f really matters if you don't use illegal parameter as the input of ColorDataFunction/Function f.

[image]

In:

```
ColorData["Gradients"]

ColorData["AlpineColors"]
ColorData["AlpineColors"][x]
ColorData["AlpineColors"][1]

Manipulate[
 ColorData["AlpineColors"][x],
 {x, 0, 1, 0.01}]
```

Out:
[image]