# Inline documentation of "Properties"

Tags: options, documentation

### Context

I find the documentation has become a bit of a maze, in particular given 
the more recent convention of having keywords has strings rather than
*Mathematica* Keywords.

For instance,

```
?PrecisionGoal
```

produced before

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But now if we use a more recent function such as

```
 ComponentMeasurements[u1, "Properties"]
```

I get this list

```
  {AdjacentBorderCount,AdjacentBorders,Area,AreaRadiusCoverage,AuthalicRadius,BoundingBox,BoundingBoxArea,BoundingDiskCenter,BoundingDiskCoverage,BoundingDiskRadius,CaliperElongation,CaliperLength,CaliperWidth,Centroid,Circularity,Complexity,ConvexArea,ConvexCount,ConvexCoverage,ConvexPerimeterLength,ConvexVertices,Count,Data,Dimensions,Eccentricity,Elongation,EmbeddedComponentCount,EmbeddedComponents,EnclosingComponentCount,EnclosingComponents,Energy,Entropy,EquivalentDiskRadius,EulerNumber,ExteriorNeighborCount,ExteriorNeighbors,FilledCircularity,FilledCount,Fragmentation,Holes,IntensityCentroid,IntensityData,InteriorNeighborCount,InteriorNeighbors,Label,LabelCount,Length,Mask,Max,MaxCentroidDistance,MaxIntensity,MaxPerimeterDistance,Mean,MeanCaliperDiameter,MeanCentroidDistance,MeanIntensity,Median,MedianIntensity,Medoid,Min,MinCentroidDistance,MinimalBoundingBox,MinIntensity,NeighborCount,Neighbors,Orientation,OuterPerimeterCount,PerimeterCount,PerimeterLength,PolygonalLength,Rectangularity,SemiAxes,Skew,StandardDeviation,StandardDeviationIntensity,Total,TotalIntensity,Width}
```

and we don't know what each option does without scanning the documentation
(where I typically get lost but that's another issue).

### Question

> Would it be possible to design a function which, given the Keyword `ComponentMeasurements`
>   and the String `"PerimeterCount"`, would return `"number of elements on the perimeter"`
>   as documented here:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> Or if this is too complicated, how can I get mathematica open the relevant documentation?

### Update

One could hack the `FullOptions` function so that FullOptions[ComponentMeasurements] would return these?

Comment: You mean for `ComponentMeasurements` or more general? The problem is that those descriptions are not usually there, are not full lists or tokens are not there at all.

Comment: For the given example I really don't see the problem. One push on the F1 button and a click on the Details section opener and you're there. 5 seconds at most.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries ok may be the example is poorly chosen. Nevertheless it would be useful to get a short description of options available for say all functions which take such stringlike options? I might be missing something behind the new philosophy but it seems to me the original one felt less like gold digging.

Comment: I feel your pain regarding *undocumented* string options (of which there are many), but in the majority of those cases there's not much we (M.SE) can do.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries so you do not know how to grab programmatically the equivalent of pressing F1 and getting the relevant section of the documentation? I don't but I wondered if someone did :-)

Comment: You can connect your function to this link contents :) [46900](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46900/5478)

Comment: The *documented* options could be found by parsing the appropriate notebook. Given their specific formatting, using the style name and the option namein a search should do the trick.

Comment: In your question there is one thing that isn't clearly stated. Basically, your question is two questions in one: First, you give an example of an **Option**. For Options, everything you say is true too, because they were real symbols and with the beginning of V6 it slowly started that more and more string-options were introduces. The other thing is, that there are more and more functions that have parameters that are like properties (or keywords). One *can* ask this in one question, but basically, it's two different things only connected by the topics *Documentation* and *String*.

Comment: @halirutan can you be more specific about the second kind of functions? e.g. give an example?

Comment: The second kind is exactly what you have with `ComponentMeasurements[input,"prop"]`. For Options, the situation is similar. When I tell you that `AxesLabel` is an option, you can instantly look-up its help-page and you see what it does. When I tell you that `"StateData"` is an option, you are lost. Even if I tell you that it is an option for `ProcessEstimator`, you will not find how it is used. Btw, I could come up with my answer because I had already thought about this unlucky situation. I planed to create an `OptionUsage` function for my packages that allows me to document string options.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Yes, it is possible:

> [image]

---

The idea is to look at the underlying cell expressions in the documentation for those string property tables. As I said already in my comment above, basically we have two different situations here:

- the trend since *Mathematica* V6 that many options are not symbols any more but rather strings.
- function arguments, that are given as strings

This leads to a *documentation shift*, because while e.g. all Options of [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) have their own *reference page*, this is not that case for the properties of [`ComponentMeasurements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html) and you can neither look at their usage message nor do they have a separate documentation page.

My implementation will make no difference between an option and a property, but it will let you access them easily.

### Implementation notes

The provides `StringProperties` function requires at least a *symbol*. It will try to open the documentation notebook-expression for this and extract all the key-value pairs that look like this

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

It will store the information in a association at gives you the chance to access them easily. The extracted values are persistent for your session, so that repeated calls will run in no-time. All information is stored in the module-variable `$db` so that it won't clash with any other symbol and hides the data from the user (I guess in javascript this is called a closure).

The important part of the functionality is hidden in the definition of `$db[...]:=..`, so you should start there. At the end of this function, an `Association` is created where the keys are string-properties (or options) and the values are the explanation extracted from the documentation page.

Another probably interesting part is the creation of the output as *usage cell*. Beware that this is only hacked. So when cells are not displayed properly, the cause is most likely in there.

### Usages

There are 3 different call patterns. To extract all string-property-names found on the help-page you can use

```
StringProperties[ColorData]
(* {"Gradients", "Indexed", "Named", "Physical", 
"ColorFunction", "ColorList", "ColorRules", "Image", "Name", "Panel", 
"ParameterCount", "Range"} *)
```

To extract the explanation of one, just put the property-name as second argument

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Or if [think you can handle it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt2io.png), then simply call e.g.

```
StringProperties[ComponentMeasurements, All]
```

### Limitations

Always remember, that the extraction relies on the structure of the help page. If the WRI stuff screwed this, it won't work. Additionally, I have found that some string properties are not only strings. For `ColorData` for instance, there exists an entry

```
{"Range",i} range of possible values for the i^th parameter
```

which can currently not be handled and is excluded.

Another thing is, that there seem to be cells that cannot simply be wrapped in a usage-style cell:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

### Code

```
StringProperties::notfound = 
  "Documentation for symbol `` could not be found.";
SetAttributes[StringProperties, {HoldFirst}];

Module[{$db},
  StringProperties[func_Symbol] := 
   With[{name = SymbolName[Unevaluated[func]]},
    Keys[$db[name]]
    ];
  StringProperties[func_Symbol, prop_String] := 
   Module[{name = SymbolName[Unevaluated[func]], doc},
    doc = $db[name][prop];
    With[{res = If[Head[doc] === Cell, doc, "Missing"]}, CellPrint[{
       Cell[BoxData[
         RowBox[{
           StyleBox[prop <> ": ", FontWeight -> Bold],
           res}]], "Print", "PrintUsage"]}]
     ]
    ];

  StringProperties[func_Symbol, All] := 
    (StringProperties[func, #] & /@ StringProperties[func];);

  $db[func_String] := $db[func] = Module[{file, nb, cells, entries},
     file = Documentation`ResolveLink[func];
     If[FileBaseName[file] =!= func, 
      Message[StringProperties::notfound, func]; Abort[]];
     nb = Import[file, "Notebook"];
     cells = Cases[nb, Cell[a_, "2ColumnTableMod", __] :> a, Infinity];
     entries = cells /. BoxData[GridBox[content_]] :> content;
     If[entries === {},
      Association[],
      Association@
       Cases[entries, {_, key_String, 
          value_Cell} :> (ToExpression[key] -> value), {2}]]
     ];
  ];
```

### Edit

Chris asked

> would it be possible to modify your answer so that it takes wildcards? Such as `StringProperties[NonlinearModelFit, "Table"]` which would be the equivalent of ?*Table* ?

You have to decide how you want this to be incorporated into the existing framework, but in general, yes this is easily possible. To give you a head-start: Let's assume you are using `StringExpressions` like `__~~"Table~~__` as wildcards, then an additional definition could look like this

```
StringProperties[func_Symbol, strExpr_StringExpression] := With[
  {
    keys = Flatten@StringCases[StringProperties[func], strExpr]
  },
  Do[StringProperties[func, k], {k, keys}]
]
```

and you are now able to do

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks: it seems to do exactly what I had in mind, and is very general and useful (IMHO!).

Comment: @halirutan: Really impressive! In case you have plans to extend your solution e.g. to overcome some of the limitations, you might consider to avoid `Association` (though elegant), as it is not available in versions below 10.

Comment: @UDB Yes, for using it through various versions one should consider using simple replacement rules instead.

Comment: What a great answer. +1

Comment: @halirutan would it be possible to modify your answer so that it takes wildcards? Such as StringProperties[NonlinearModelFit, "*Table*"] which would be the equivalent of ?*Table*  ?

Comment: @chris See my edit at the end of the answer.

Comment: @halirutan great! I have already up voted your answer though :-)

Comment: Could you please tell me why the first fails and the second works?: `mesh = DiscretizeRegion[Disk[]];
mesh2 = ToElementMesh[mesh];
StringProperties[Evaluate@Head@mesh, All]
StringProperties[Evaluate@Head@mesh2, All]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to get you started. It opens the documentation notebook and looks for a table row containing the appropriate string. I haven't tested it thoroughly so there are sure to be problems:

```
findInDocs[s_Symbol, p_String] := fID[ToString[s], "\"" <> p <> "\""]
findInDocs[s_Symbol, p_Symbol] := fID[ToString[s], ButtonBox[ToString@p, __]]

fID[s_, p_] := Module[{fname, n, nb},
  fname = ToFileName[{$InstallationDirectory,
     "Documentation", "English", "System", "ReferencePages", "Symbols"}, s <> ".nb"];
  nb = NotebookGet[n = NotebookOpen[fname, Visible -> False]]; 
  NotebookClose[n];
  Column[Replace[Cases[nb, {Cell[_, "TableRowIcon"],
       p, default___, Cell[x_String, "TableText"]} :> {x, default}, -1],
    {{x_, d_} :> Row[{x, "   ", ToExpression@d}], {x_} :> x}, 1]]]
```

Examples

```
findInDocs[ComponentMeasurements, "PerimeterCount"]
```

> number of elements on the perimeter

```
findInDocs[Image, ColorSpace]
```

> what color space to assume for the data   **Automatic**

In the last one the `Automatic` is the default value for `ColorSpace`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this `u = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {20, 20}] // Image; pp = ComponentMeasurements[u, "Properties"];
findInDocs[ComponentMeasurements, #] & /@ (pp[[Range[5]]])`
it seems to take a while.

Comment: @Simon Have you seen in my answer that there is a function ``Documentation`ResolveLink`` which gives you the filename for the doc-notebook easily?

Comment: @halirutan, nice find. I went looking for useful functions like that but got lost among the legacy code for the old documentation centre. Your answer is really great.

Comment: your answer doe do the job, if only a bit slowly.