# Better output for NonlinearModelFit "ParameterTable"

Tags: pattern-matching, fitting

The Standard table fo parameters of NonlinearModelFit is obtained from

```
 NonlinearModelFit[{{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 3}}, a + b*x, {a, b}, x]
 %["ParameterTable"]]
```

I woud like to manipulate the numbers in this tabe to my taste.

For some of this I could "ParameterTableEntries", but this gives just the numerical values, not the name of the parameters.

So I would like to know if there is an way to get the fit parameters names in the right order.

My best guess is to manipulate the output of `InputForm[%["ParameterTable"]]`, but I failed so far because of my poor pattern search skills ... any idea?

Thanks,
Roberto

Comment: try `fit = NonlinearModelFit[{{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 3}}, a + b*x, {a, b}, x]; fit  /@ fit["Properties"]` any of it of interest to you?

Comment: it seems `fit["ParameterTableEntries"]` is what you want?

Comment: no Chris, this is not what I want, as I have pointed out in my original message this function gives only the numerical values, not the names of the paramters, which is what I am ultimately after.

Comment: this then: 'fit["ParameterTable"] // First // First // Flatten // 
 Take[#, {1, 6}] &'

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have typed

```
 fit = NonlinearModelFit[{{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {3, 3}}, a + b*x, {a, b}, x]
```

Using this [great answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77373/1089)

you can type

```
  StringProperties[NonlinearModelFit]
```

{BestFit,BestFitParameters,Data,Function,Response,FitResiduals,StandardizedResiduals,StudentizedResiduals,ANOVATable,ANOVATableDegreesOfFreedom,ANOVATableEntries,ANOVATableMeanSquares,ANOVATableSumsOfSquares,EstimatedVariance,CorrelationMatrix,CovarianceMatrix,ParameterBias,ParameterConfidenceIntervals,ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable,ParameterConfidenceIntervalTableEntries,ParameterConfidenceRegion,ParameterErrors,ParameterPValues,ParameterTable,ParameterTableEntries,ParameterTStatistics,CurvatureConfidenceRegion,FitCurvatureTable,FitCurvatureTableEntries,MaxIntrinsicCurvature,MaxParameterEffectsCurvature,HatDiagonal,SingleDeletionVariances,MeanPredictionBands,MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervals,MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervalTable,MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervalTableEntries,MeanPredictionErrors,PredictedResponse,SinglePredictionBands,SinglePredictionConfidenceIntervals,SinglePredictionConfidenceIntervalTable,SinglePredictionConfidenceIntervalTableEntries,SinglePredictionErrors,AdjustedRSquared,AIC,AICc,BIC,RSquared}

then you can type

```
StringProperties[NonlinearModelFit, All]
```

and get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You will easily see that what you want is

```
  fit["ParameterTableEntries"]
```

(
1.14286 0.225877    5.05964 0.124222
0.642857    0.123718    5.19615 0.121038
)

### Update

If you want the headers this ought to do it

```
 fit["ParameterTable"] // First // First // Flatten // 
 Take[#, {1, 6}] &
```

Comment: Great way to get the information on the parameters, but I am not after the table entries, I am after the table headings, i.e. the names of the fit parameters. I think there is no way to miss that "parameters names" is what  I am after, so I have to down-vote this answer. Sorry.

Comment: Dear Chris, Thanks for this attempt. Your {1,6} seems to be specific to a case you were trying, as it does not work on the example I posted. I think is more general to do `Drop[(%["ParameterTable"] // First // First)[[All, 1]], 1]` which returns the whole column of parameters.

Comment: @RobertoFranceschini well you can now answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Drop[(%["ParameterTable"] // First // First)[[All, 1]], 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = Table[{x, Exp[.2 + .3 x + .1 Sin[x] + RandomReal[{-.2, .2}]]},
             {x, RandomReal[5, 100]}]; 
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Exp[a + b Sin[x] + c Cos[x]], {a, b, c}, x];
pt = nlm["ParameterTable"];
```

You can also use `Part` as follows to access the row labels, column labels and the content of `pt`:

```
rowlabels = Sequence[1, 1, 2 ;;, 1];
collabels = Sequence[1, 1, 1, 2 ;;];
content = Sequence[1, 1, 2 ;;, 2 ;;];

pt[[rowlabels]]
(* {a, b, c} *)

pt[[collabels]]
(* {"Estimate", "Standard Error", "t-Statistic", "P-Value"} *)

pt[[content]]
(* {{1.00159, 0.0252967, 39.5938, 1.10726*10^-61},
    {-0.375734, 0.0304626, -12.3343, 1.3907*10^-21},
    {-0.157534, 0.0357183, -4.41046, 0.0000267067}} *)

pt[[content]] == nlm["ParameterTableEntries"]
(* True *)

Row[Labeled[#, #2, Top] & @@@ {{pt,"ParameterTable\n"},
    {MapAt[Style[2 #, Red, 20] &, pt, {{1, 1, 2, 4}}], 
     "ParameterTable\nwith part {1,1,2,4} modified"}}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]