# "Typical supported forms include..."

Tags: documentation

The following is an excerpt from the official documentation for `Placed` (emphasis added):

> - ***Typical supported forms include*** `Bottom`, `Left`, `Center`, `Right`, `Top`, `Tooltip`, `StatusArea`, as well as special positions associated with particular charts or other constructs, and explicit lists of scaled coordinates.

Is there a systematic way to find *all* the forms supported by `Placed`?

---

FWIW, my immediate application is labeling the bars in barcharts, but I really would prefer a comprehensive answer.

Comment: I suspect (though I am far from sure) that the supported forms depend on the context where `Placed` is used.  This is why it is talking about *typical* value. This is not specific to `Placed`. There are e.g. some option names which can be used in different functions and take similar but non-identical values.

Comment: For example, you can place a plot legend above the plot, but not in the status area or in a tooltip. You can place the `VertexLabels` in tooltips though. While I agree that the documentation could be improved in some places, I think that the question would turn out much better (i.e. attract actually useful answers) if you asked about one specific context (or class of contexts) where you are using `Placed`.

Comment: related: [How to get a list of available appearance/styles/Methods?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18918/5478)