# How can I find lists of front-end option values?

Tags: front-end, undocumented

Things like `Slider` have special option values like `Appearance -> "LeftArrow"`. How can I find all of the possible values it takes, since I can't even look at the `DownValues` for it?

Comment: at least closely related: [18918](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18918/5478)

Answer (score 3):

One option is to see what the Options Inspector has for you. It's tedious, though, to look this up manually though, so here's a way to automatically import these:

```
oiOps =
  StringCases[
    Import[
     FrontEndExecute@
      FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath["OptionInspectorStrings.tr", 
       "PrivatePathsTextResources"], "String"],
    "@@resource" ~~ r : Except["\n"] .. ~~ "StringTable" :> 
     StringTrim[r]
    ] // AssociationMap[FrontEndResource[# <> "StringTable"] &];
```

(Note that I'm only selecting those resource names with `"StringTable"` at the end. There are others there to work with too.)

Then:

```
oiOps["sliderAppearance"]

{"Automatic", "None", "Default", "Vertical", "LeftArrow", \
"RightArrow", "UpArrow", "DownArrow"}
```

And we can see these are the appearances the options inspector knows about.

A cool set of options many of which I didn't know about:

```
oiOps["buttonFrame"]

{"Automatic", "None", "\"Frameless\"", "\"Framed\"", "\"Button\"", \
"\"DialogBox\"", "\"Palette\"", "\"FramedPalette\"", "\"Tab\"", \
"\"ActiveTab\"", "\"AbuttingRight\"", "\"AbuttingLeftRight\"", \
"\"AbuttingLeft\"", "\"DefaultButton\"", "\"CancelButton\"", \
"\"ColorSetter\"", "\"Popup\"", "\"PopupMenu\"", "\"ActionMenu\"", \
"\"TextField\"", "\"ComboBox\""}
```

(Note that `"TextField"` and `"ComboBox"` seem to be there to implement [this](https://youtu.be/fz8yznsivPc?t=18m54s) stuff)

Even if it's in this list, it may still not have an effect. Of these:

```
oiOps["locatorAppearance"]

{"Automatic", "None", "Default", "Point", "Thumb", "Crosshairs"}
```

Only `None` does anything different for me.