# EquationNumbered counter resets

Tags: formatting, customization

I have a notebook where the number on the `"EquationNumbered"` cell goes from (6) to (1) within the same section.  Is there any way to manually correct equation numbers?

I seem to encounter this issue regularly.  Would it be possible to create a equation numbered cell without the automatic equation numbering?

Ideally, I would like to keep the parenthesis on the right-hand side of the page and simply allow an equation number to be entered instead of assigned.

The current `"CounterFunction"` under Automatic Numbering Options in Cell Properties is set to `"Identity"` with no parameter specified. Would it be possible to

1. Make the equation number editable.
2. Change the `"CounterFunction"`

Are there any third-party applications that would allow me to do advanced formatting of Mathematica notebooks to address such items as editing equation numbering, produce sections containing two side-by-side columns of text, formatting tables, etc...?

**Additional Info:**
When I change the stylesheet to Standard Report and set the cell types to `"DisplayFormulaNumbered"`, the equation numbering works properly.

This seems to be a problem with the `"EquationNumbered"` cell type.

Comment: Two-column would be hard to support. It's possible, if you're clever about it, but tough. The smartest way to do it would be to have a two-column cell type that automatically splits itself when viewed in the `"Printout"` style.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to assume you're using the `"Book/Textbook"` style, because I can't remember where else I've seen `"EquationNumbered"`.

If so, we can figure out what would reset the counter for `"EquationNumbered"` like so:

```
counterAssignments =
  With[{
     styles =
      FE`Evaluate@
        FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListStyles"] // Values
     },
    AssociationMap[
     CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],
       {StyleDefinitions, #, "CounterAssignments"}
       ] &,
     styles
     ]
    ] // DeleteCases[$Failed | {}];

Select[counterAssignments, Not@*FreeQ["EquationNumbered"]] // Keys

{"BookChapterNumber", "Title", "Subtitle"}
```

So you must have one of those somewhere in your section?

If so, just add `CounterAssignments->None` to the cell.

As for changing the `CounterFunction`, we can see what sort of things are supported by using my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155979/38205):

```
oiOps["counterFunction"]

{{"Decimal Numbers", "Identity"}, {"Roman Numerals", 
  "RomanNumeral"}, {"Capital Roman Numerals", 
  "CapitalRomanNumeral"}, {"abc...", 
  "(Part[CharacterRange[\"a\", \"z\"], #]&)"}, {"ABC...", 
  "(Part[CharacterRange[\"A\", \"Z\"], #]&)"}, {"Greek Letters", 
  "(Part[CharacterRange[\"\\[Alpha]\", \"\\[Omega]\"], #]&)"}, \
{"Capital Greek Letters", 
  "(Part[CharacterRange[\"\\[CapitalAlpha]\", \"\\[CapitalOmega]\"], \
#]&)"}, {"Circled numbers", 
  "(Part[CharacterRange[\"\\:2460\", \"\\:2469\"], #]&)"}, {"Black \
circled numbers", 
  "(Part[CharacterRange[\"\\:2776\", \"\\:277F\"], #]&)"}, {"Black \
sans-serif circled numbers", 
  "(Part[CharacterRange[\"\\:278A\", \"\\:2793\"], #]&)"}, {"Days of \
the week", 
  "(Part[{\"Monday\", \"Tuesday\", \"Wednesday\", \"Thursday\", \
\"Friday\", \"Saturday\", \"Sunday\"}, #]&)"}, {"Months", 
  "(Part[{\"January\", \"February\", \"March\", \"April\", \"May\", \
\"June\", \"July\", \"August\", \"September\", \"October\", \
\"November\", \"December\"}, #]&)"}, Delimiter, {"Other Mathematica \
Function", None}}
```

The way you change the `CounterFunction` at the style level is to set it in the `CounterBoxOptions`. Note that this seems to *only* work with a limited subset of functions. Generally it seems only `Identity`, `RomanNumeral`, and the `Part[CharacterRange[...], ...]` constructions are allowed.

In any case, here's a way to tag things with Korean vowel characters. Ignore the `SSEdit`. Just assume you're doing these edits to the `"EquationNumbered"` cell at the stylesheet level.

```
SSEdit["EquationNumbered",
 {
  CellFrameLabels -> {
    {
     None,
     Cell[TextData[{"(", CounterBox["EquationNumbered"], ")"}]]
     },
    {None, None}
    },
  CounterBoxOptions -> {
    CounterFunction -> Function[CharacterRange["ᅡ", "ᆁ"][[#]]]
    }
  },
 "MakeCell" -> True
 ]
```

[image: asd]

As for manual equation number editing, you can do that through the `CellFrameLabels` without much trouble. Just do a `Button` that pops up a dialog to call `SetOptions` on the cell or set something like `CurrentValue[{TaggingRules, "EquationNumbers", someTag}] = number` and then have a `Dynamic[CurrentValue[{TaggingRules, "EquationNumbers", someTag}], RawBoxes[CounterBox["EquationNumbered"]]]` or in the `Button` label.