# NumberedItem but with letters

Tags: formatting, stylesheet, style

Is there a way to change the headings on NumberedItem style?

Instead of it going

1.

2.

3.

I am looking for it to go

A.

B.

C.

with the auto increment. I can't find a style that has headings as letters.

Comment: What after `Z`?

Comment: @Kuba internally they actually handle this problem via `CharacterRange`. I think this question is a dupe of one I answered a few weeks back, but I'll need to look it up.

Comment: @Kuba I only need it up to `D` so I hadn't considered that yet.
@b3m2a1 I tried searching but I don't know how to phrase it. I looked for 'numbereditem string header' and similar but had no results. I just look through your answers for 'itemnumbered' and 'item', didn't find anything.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Not sure I understand, where do they handle what? I know we can refer to character codes but what if user expects excel like convention, `AA,AB,...`.

Comment: @Kuba if you look at the standard `CounterFunction` definitions they all look like `Function[CharacterRange[n1, n2][[#]]]` when not defined by string. I know the user might expect something else. That's just what Mathematica provides.

Comment: @b3m2a1 thanks, I wasn't expecting `CharacterRange` in stylesheets.

Comment: @Kuba neither was I. Here's where I dug this up: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159829/38205

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Can I also change the delimiter in `CounterBoxOption` from ending in `.` to ending in `)` or `-`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this in the style sheet. So:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["ItemNumbered"],
            CellDingbat->Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["ItemNumbered"], ")"}],FontWeight->Bold],
            CounterBoxOptions->{CounterFunction->(CharacterRange["A","Z"][[#1]]&)}
        ]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```

where I used ")" instead of "." as requested in a comment.

Answer (score 4):

From @b3m2a1's linked post [mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159829/38205](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159829/38205)

```
Cell["a", "ItemNumbered",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.72170647675723*^9, 3.7217064817685165`*^9}},
 CounterBoxOptions -> {
    CounterFunction -> Function[CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[#]]]
    }]
```